# Why does .text().replace() delete my html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

[FIDDLE UPDATED TO CLASSES](http://jsfiddle.net/4UThx/4/)

```
<p id="boohoo"><b id="why did all this disappear">Old Text</b></p>    
<p id="boohoo"><h4 id="why did this not work">Old Text</h4></p>
```

---

```
var x = $('#boohoo').text().replace('Old', 'New'); 
function whyNotBold() {
    $('#boohoo').text(x); 
}
```

Why is there a difference between `<b>` and `<h4>`?  And how can I have the the former `<b id="...` html not disappear when I insert the text? I would think `.text().replace(...` would only replace text and not affect the html, but that doesnt seem to be the case here since it's deleting it.

Comment: Don't have duplicate IDs - that's not allowed. Use classes instead. It'll only return one result.

Comment: You can't use the same "id" value for more than one element.

Comment: .text() is for text, not html. it will replace the contents of the selected element with whatever you pass to it, as documented in the api.

Comment: Why do you need the `text()` part at all? Just call `replace()`

Comment: I tried classes http://jsfiddle.net/4UThx/4/ , but that doesn't delete the `<h4>` tag or keep the `<b>` tag.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firt of all you have 2 element with the same id, this is wrong. So your replacement work with the first element only.

The second is text() function strips tags and return only text content of your first node which is: `Old Text`. When you use text() func to set the text, jquery thinks you want your node `<p id="boohoo">` contains text **ONLY** and it makes this:

```
<p id="boohoo">New Text</p>
```

Becase text() func resonsible for [text nodes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp)

**EDIT**:

In your case, you can do what you want like this:

```
var x = $('b').text().replace('Old', 'New'); 

function whyNotBold() {
    $('b').text(x); 
    $('h4').text(x); 
}
setTimeout(whyNotBold, 300);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4UThx/5/)

Comment: Ok i think i see.  Is there anyway to manipulate text than without deleting html?

Comment: Yes, target the element that contains the text.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it targeting the parent element since I wouldn't know what html would be inside or next to the element? (i.e. it could be like `Here are <b>words</b> in <i>my</i> application....` and I want to target and replace `application` without deleting all the other tags

Comment: Yes thank u.  Essentially I didn't know that calling text() would delete all the html within that element.  That I suppose is my problem.